# UITableViewCell won't be swiped to trigger action more than once since iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, ios11

I'm having a regression in my app since Apple released iOS 11 and the `trailingSwipeActions` feature.

My `TableView` displays messages and lets the user delete them by displaying a Delete button on swipe left.

It works perfectly but not on iOS 11. The swipe action can only be done once and then it's just not working anymore for all the rows, the cells just don't swipe. I have the following message in the debug console.

> *** NSForwarding: warning: method signature and compiler disagree on struct-return-edness of 'prepareWithSwipeDirection:configuration:'. 
>   Signature thinks it does not return a struct, and compiler thinks it
>   does.

**The `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath`** **method gets called every time**, but the cell just doesn't swipe.

I've tried to implement all the new functions coming with iOS 11 regarding this feature but nothing fixes my issue.

Also trying to figure out if some GestureRecognizer was randomly "eating" the gesture but didn't find anything relevant, it's also hard to debug.

Here's the relevant code after different changes I tried:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canFocusRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return NO;
}


- (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        UIContextualAction * delete = [UIContextualAction contextualActionWithStyle:UIContextualActionStyleDestructive title:@"Delete" handler:^(UIContextualAction * _Nonnull action, __kindof UIView * _Nonnull sourceView, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(BOOL)) {
            [self deleteMessageAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }];
        UISwipeActionsConfiguration *configuration = [UISwipeActionsConfiguration configurationWithActions:@[delete]];
        configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false;
        return configuration;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewRowAction * delete = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDestructive title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction * action, NSIndexPath * indexPath){
        [self deleteMessageAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }];
    return @[delete];
}

- (void) deleteMessageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *threadID = [[self.messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"threadID"];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.messageArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    //[self.tableView reloadData];

    @weakify(self);
    [UIUtil showLoadingHudWithText: @"Deleting..."];
    [[AsyncUtil sharedInstance] dispatch_background_network:^{
        DBManager *db = [[DBManager alloc] init];
        [db deletetableData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"singleChat WHERE threadID = '%@' ",threadID] ];
        [[MemChatThreadMessages sharedInstance] removeThread:threadID];
        NSDictionary * result = [Network deleteChatThread:threadID forEmail:[WEUtil getEmail]];
        [[AsyncUtil sharedInstance] dispatch_main:^{
            [UIUtil hideLoadingHuds];
            @strongify(self);
            if(self == nil) return ;

            if([result[@"result"] isEqualToString:@"success"]){

            }else{
                //[self.tableView reloadData];
                [UIUtil showErrorMessage:@"Cannot delete this thread"];
            }
        }];
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why is your method defined to return id and not UISwipeActionsConfiguration?

Comment: Thanks for helping, I fixed it and tried again with same results.

Comment: Found a piece of information about the problem here (in Chinese) : http://fanwt.com/2017/12/08/iOS11%E4%B8%ADUITableViewCell%E4%B8%8D%E8%83%BD%E4%BE%A7%E6%BB%91%E7%BC%96%E8%BE%91%E7%9A%84%E8%AF%A1%E5%BC%82%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98/

Comment: The same thing is working for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to swizzling induced by a snipped in my code :

```
@implementation NSMutableDictionary (NilSafe)


- (void)gl_setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(id<NSCopying>)key {
    if (!key) {
        return;
    }
    if (!obj) {
        obj = [NSNull null];
    }
    [self gl_setObject:obj forKeyedSubscript:key];
}

@end
```

This part is where the bug was induced :

```
    if (!obj) {
        obj = [NSNull null];
    }
```

Changing `obj = [NSNull null];` to `return;` fixed the issue.

Original blog post on the problem solution is [here](http://fanwt.com/2017/12/08/iOS11%E4%B8%ADUITableViewCell%E4%B8%8D%E8%83%BD%E4%BE%A7%E6%BB%91%E7%BC%96%E8%BE%91%E7%9A%84%E8%AF%A1%E5%BC%82%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98/) (in Chinese).